# What could this Regex algorithm be for?

Tags: regex

Can anyone tell me what Regex algorithm this is?

```
^0[1-10]
{3}-[1-10]
{3}-[1-10]{3}$
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This pattern doesn't make much sense, for one thing.  I would much easier for us to help you if you could tell us what the pattern is supposed to be doing.

Comment: It looks like regexp written by someone who don't understand regexp. Take the first example. `^` means "starts with" so a number that starts with `0`. `[]` means any of these characters. `-` has a special meaning inside `[]` - it means range. So `[1-10]` means either from `1` to `1` or `0`. This can be simplified to `[10]`. So the first regexp matches anything that starts with `0` followed by `1` or `0`. It can be more efficiently written as `^0[01]` but I'm guessing the author intended to write `^0[0-9]`

Comment: `[1-10]` seriously looks like a bug that should have been `[0-9]`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guys. Unfortunately, this is all the code that was given to me as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can look at this regex as one of three possibilities:

- take it as-is
- make it into one line, with spaces
- make it into one line, no spaces

needless to say, all three yield different match results. I use regex101.com to explain regex matches.

- as-is: https://regex101.com/r/pQWPB7/1/ (this doesn't look useful)
- one line, with spaces: https://regex101.com/r/5928TV/1/ (this doesn't look useful either)
- one line, no spaces: https://regex101.com/r/khD1LI/1/ (this makes sense, however...)

the pattern `[1-10]` is (most likely) a typo. the question probably meant "numbers 1 through 10" but instead it says "any of: `1`, `0`, `-`"

if i replace `[1-10]` with `[0-9]` the expression is much more useful. Take a look at this: https://regex101.com/r/khD1LI/3/

this now looks like an expression to capture some sort of numeric code

---

you can further clarify the meaning by replacing `[0-9]` with `\d` which is a [shorthand class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) for all digits

here's a viz of the matching process: [https://regexper.com/#^0\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$](https://regexper.com/#%5E0%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B3%7D$)

[image]

Comment: perl's `m/.../x` allows whitespace, as does PCRE's `(?x)...`, just as two examples

Answer (score 2):

@lawrencealan is correct about the literal matches, but if the regex were fixed to

```
^0[1-9]{3}-[1-9]{3}-[1-9]{3}$
```

then it would match

```
0XXX-XXX-XXX
```

where X can only be numbers 1-9, not 0. For example, these would all match:

```
0748-283-991
0845-854-768
0478-982-749
```

But not:

```
0840-324-876
0489-006-010
1324-987-345
```

Answer (score -1):

That Regex looks malformed... so probably nothing in it's current state...
If you fix it, though:

`^0[1-10]{3}-[1-10]{3}-[1-10]{3}$`

Will match these lines:

```
0XXX-XXX-XXX
0XXX-XXX-XXX
0XXX-XXX-XXX
```

Where X is either `1` or `0`

So, the first two, but not the last of these lines:

```
0111-101-000
0001-010-101
0333-100-111
```